# How to remove Autofill in inputType editText

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

How to remove this recommendation TAB with previously used email Id that appears when i click on the edit text . [Email Tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvY5d.jpg)

How to make that color TRANSPARENT once I've selected one them.[Selected Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkxhC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your xml to disable the auto fill

```
android:importantForAutofill="no"
```

if it doesn't work, could you please include your EditText xml